# httpget not working due to "not trusted server certificate" but it works with httpost

Tags: android, gettext

I have a code that needs to go to the website below and extract the text. In another part of the project I use the httpost method and it gives me a response based on what I've sent. However for the httpget function suddenly it gives me an exception saying javax.net.ssl.SSLEXCEPTION:Not trusted server certificate.

Is there a way to fix this? I don't understand why one method works while the other doesn't. Thanks

```
     //some code
    getText("https://iphone-radar.com/accounts/4e3f2c6659f25a0f8400000b");

}
    public static void getText(String uri) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri); 

        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            // Examine the response status


            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            android.util.Log.v("EXCEPTION","["+e.getMessage()+"]", e);



        }
    }
```

Comment: http://iphone-radar.com/accounts/4e3f2c6659f25a0f8400000b gives the same results, is it an option to use the non-ssl site?

Comment: using the website without https and using http instead does indeed work! However is there a way to still use https for security purposes?

Comment: iphone-radar.com has a certificate chain of 3 certificate, the root CA or the intermediate is not installed among android trusted certificates (thus, the security error). i know no programmatic method of installing certificates, one way could be opening in the phone browser the certificate in PEM format directly: that should fire up the certificate import dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem while developing an app for my school. The trick is to create two classes that override certificate verification.
One extends HostnameVerifier and returns true every time verify() is called, like [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-tjintranet/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/tjhsst/androidIntranet/login/AllVerifier.java).
The other class extends X509TrustManager and overrides getAcceptedIssuers() like [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-tjintranet/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/tjhsst/androidIntranet/login/AllTrustManager.java).

Then you can set the HttpsURLConnection to accept all certificates using this code:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new AllVerifier());
try {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new AllTrustManager() }, null);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
} catch (KeyManagementException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That should do the trick. You can see how I used this code [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-tjintranet/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/tjhsst/androidIntranet/login/LoginIOThread.java), in the run() method.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like below to override the verifier. Code tested using Android 2.2

```
 /**
   * Will cause HttpsURLConnection to accept even self-signed certificates.
   * @param conn
   */
  private static void trustEveryone(HttpsURLConnection conn) {
    try {
      conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
          return true;
        }
      });
      SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] aChain, String aAuthType)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] aChain, String aAuthType)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
        }
      } }, new SecureRandom());
      conn.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) { //handle accordingly
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply ignore all the SSL cert check. The comment on the following link helped me!

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1946#c10